# How to use GraphicsGrid with ListPlots that have a PlotLegend?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Here's a contrived example of what I'm trying to do. Basically, I want a function to return some object that has two plots next to each other (or one on top of the other), both large, and both with legends.

```
test1 = Table[Table[{x, a*x^2}, {x, -10, 10}], {a, 2}]
test2 = Table[Table[{x, b*x^4}, {x, -10, 10}], {b, 3}]
testplot1 = ListPlot[test1];
testplot2 = ListPlot[test2];
GraphicsGrid[{{testplot1, testplot2}}]
```

That's good, I like how large they are on my screen, and it's cool that they're next to each other.

But if I add PlotLegends:

```
test1 = Table[Table[{x, a*x^2}, {x, -10, 10}], {a, 2}]
test2 = Table[Table[{x, b*x^4}, {x, -10, 10}], {b, 3}]
testplot1 = ListPlot[test1, PlotLegends -> Automatic];
testplot2 = ListPlot[test2, PlotLegends -> Automatic];
GraphicsGrid[{{testplot1, testplot2}}]
```

I get this fun stuff:

[image]

This is really annoying. Adding ImageSize->Large to GraphicsGrid doesn't help. How can I make them larger but still have legends? Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming you have to assign a GraphicsGrid size.  If you assign a ListPlot size instead you avoid this issue entirely(I'm not quiet sure if it is technicaly bug).

Comment: @William, thanks for the comment. Sorry, I'm not totally sure what you mean: how do you assign listplot a size? I didn't know that you could use imagesize as an option for it.

Comment: Please let me know if Rasterizing them is an issue and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: How about `testplot1 = ListPlot[test1, ImageSize -> 200, PlotLegends -> Automatic];   testplot2 = ListPlot[test2, ImageSize -> 200, PlotLegends -> Automatic];  GraphicsGrid[{{testplot1, testplot2}}, ImageSize -> 500]`.

Comment: Which version are you using? I don't see any issues for 10.2 on Win 8.1 Pro 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

March's comment works well.

```
testplot1 = ListPlot[test1, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 200];
testplot2 = ListPlot[test2, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 200];
GraphicsGrid[{{testplot1, testplot2}}, ImageSize -> 500,
       Background -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0, 0.1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that it has some space above and below the plot.

Sometimes when I want finer control over the graphics I use `Row`, `Column` or `Grid` rather than the graphics counterpart.

```
Row[{testplot1, Spacer[20], testplot2},
      Background -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0, 0.1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can add space to the left, middle or right using `Spacer` and control the vertical space by making the spacer parameters a list. For example

```
Spacer[{20,250,100}]
```

will create a space 20 points wide, 250 points high and 100 points below the baseline.

In the example below we add a margin of 10 points on each side, 20 points between the plot and 50 points above (i.e., 250-200) and 100 points below.

```
Row[{
  Style[Spacer[{10, 20}], Background -> Red],
  testplot1,
  Style[Spacer[{20, 250, 100}], Background -> Red],
  testplot2,
  Style[Spacer[{10, 20}], Background -> Red]
  },
  Background -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0, 0.1]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The color is just to show the `Spacer`. Color would not be used in a production plot.

Answer (score 0):

If you rasterize them its easy as Pi.

```
test1 = Table[Table[{x, a*x^2}, {x, -10, 10}], {a, 2}]
test2 = Table[Table[{x, b*x^4}, {x, -10, 10}], {b, 3}]
testplot1 = 
  Rasterize[ListPlot[test1, PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
   ImageSize -> 600];
testplot2 = 
  ListPlot[test2, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 600];
GraphicsGrid[{{testplot1, testplot2}}]
```

Comment: I don't think we want to `Rasterize` any of the plots or components, lest we get aliasing when rescaling them for publication or display at a different size.  Isn't there another way to avoid the scaling problem identified by the question poser?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If you find one please post it.  I recall issues with this but don't remember the solution